# C address of operator for struct but not for array?

Tags: c, struct

Why is it that I can do....

```
int numbers[100];
int * intPtr = numbers;
```

NOT using the address of operator but...

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Vec2D;

Vec2D vec;
Vec2D * vecPtr = &vec;
```

That is, why is the address of operator required on the struct? Why isn't `vec` an address?

Comment: I think instead of `foo`, you mean `numbers`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analogy is broken: The fair comparison would be between `Vec2D *` and `int (*)[100]`, i.e. pointers to the object. However, in your first piece of code, you are obtaining a pointer to a *subobject* using an unrelated language mechanism (array-to-pointer decay).

The following works as expected:

```
typedef int T[100];
T numbers;
T * p = &numbers;   // or: int (*p)[100] = &numbers;

typedef Vec2D T;
T vec;
T * p = &vec;       // or: Vec2D * p = &vec;
```

Pointers to subobjects can also be taken:

```
int * p_elem = &numbers[0];
int * v_emen = &vec.x;
```

The only special magic rule is that the array expression `numbers` can *decay* to the address of its first element, so `&numbers[0]` is the same as (the result of) `numbers`:

```
int * p_elem = numbers;  // same as &numbers[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of size *N* are basically a pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory containing *N* objects. The `[i]` operator specifies the offset from the pointer where the *ith* object is. So basically `numbers` by itself is just a pointer.
For instance,

```
int main(){
int numbers[100];
numbers[0] = 1;
printf ("%d\n", numbers);
}
```

will throw an error because numbers it a pointer, not an integer.